# Why does moveCamera cause an exception when called outside of the getMapAsync method?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on an app that allows users to put tags on a Google Map. To do this, I need to be able to move the map's camera position to certain latitude/longitude coordinates. Here are the related methods:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_screen, container, false);
    mMapFrag = (SupportFragmentManager) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mMapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
    CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(mLat, mLon));
    mMap.moveCamera(center);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mMapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
    CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(mLat, mLon));
    mMap.moveCamera(center);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
}
```

moveCamera() causes a NullPointerException. Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

Comment: Looks like you already have `mMap` as a class level instance variable.  Why even use a GoogleMap object as a parameter in your `moveMapCamera()` function?  Just use `mMap` instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I don't actually have this method in my code. Instead, I call this in the onCreate method. Could this have something to do with the problem?

Comment: I have tried to use getMapAsync() and the onMapReady() callback to instantiate the map. This still does not seem to work. I have a feeling that the onMapReady() callback is taking too long. Is there a way for me to wait for the onMapReady() callback to complete before executing additional code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callback onMapReady() gives the inflated/generated map object that you can use in your code which is a async callback. Till then the map object remains uninitialized.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    map.moveCamera(center);
}
```

change `onMapReady()` code with above snippet.

Also, if you wish to do that on your onResume also, then you can check if the map object is null and if it is null

```
if(mapFrag == null){
    mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this)
}
```

Use above snippet in your `onResume()`
That should work.

Answer (score 0):

Move this line to `onMapReady`.. After you initialize the map variable.

```
map.moveCamera(center);
```

Otherwise, the map is null. Doesn't matter what method you've called on it. It's going to be null where you currently have it.

Also, pick the correct `mMap` or `map` variable to use. Then, you also will want to initialize `mapFrag` in `onCreateView`. You have the line to find the Fragment, but don't do anything with it